# Filter readings PIC

Tags: c, pic

I am using a PIC and a proximity sensor to read the distance in cm away from an object.

The result is stored in

> Distance = Rf_Rx_Buff[6].

Basically instead of using that result I want to implement a filter which takes 10 readings, averages them out and only allows the average to be read out in Rf_Rx_Buff[6] .

Could anyone guide me on how to implement this.

Comment: And what's your problem? Read the value 10 times and calculate the moving average.

Comment: Yes but that is what I am struggling with, how to implement the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least 3 approaches:

1. Read 10 values and return the average (easy)

   ```
   unsigned Distance1(void) {
     unsigned Average_Distance = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       Average_Distance += Rf_Rx_Buff[6];
     }
     Average_Distance = (Average_Distance + 5)/10;  // +5 for rounding
     return Average_Distance;
   }
   ```
2. Read once, but return the average of the last 10 reads:

   ```
   unsigned Distance2(void) {
     static unsigned Distance[10];
     static unsigned Count = 0;
     static unsigned Index = 0;
     Distance[Index++] = Rf_Rx_Buff[6];
     if (Index >= 10) {
       Index = 0;
     }
     Count++;
     if (Count > 10) {
       Count = 10;
     }
     unsigned long Average_Distance = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       Average_Distance += Distance[i];
     }
     Average_Distance = (Average_Distance + Count/2)/Count;
     return Average_Distance;
   }
   ```
3. Read once, but return the the running average ([digital low pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization)):

   ```
   unsigned Distance3(void) {
     static unsigned long Sum = 0;
     static int First = 1;
     if (First) {
       First = 0;
       Sum =  Rf_Rx_Buff[6] * 10;
     } else {
       Sum = Rf_Rx_Buff[6] + (Sum*9)/10;
     }
     return (Sum + 5)/10;
   }
   ```

Other simplifications and approaches possible,

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way:

1.) Develop a function that calculates the average.

```
int calc_average(int *sensor_values, int number_sensor_values) {
    int result = 0;
    for(char i = 0; i < number_sensor_values; ++i) {
        // calculate average
        result += *sensor_values++...
        ....
    }
    ....
    return result;
}
```

2.) Read 10 sensor data and store the data in an array (`sensor_values`).

3.) Call your `calc_average` function and pass the `sensor_values` array to get the result.